$p$-norm of random variables and weighted $L^p$ space resemblance
I noticed a very similar relationship between weighted $L^p$ space (denoted $L_w^p$) and normed vector space of random variables. I want to unify these two spaces but there always seems to be a difference, or are they actually different?
Recall that $L_w^p$-norm is defined if the following integral exists:
$$
\left\| f \right\|_{L_w^p} := \left( \int |f(x)|^p w(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.
$$
The $p$-norm of a real-valued R.V. $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined to be:
$$
\left\| X \right\|_p := \mathbb{E}[|X|^p]^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left(\int_\Omega |X|^p \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left(\int_\mathbb{R} |x|^p f_X(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
    \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $f_X(x)$ is the p.d.f. of R.V. $X$.
You can prove that these two norms are indeed norms with triangle inequality:
$$
\left\| f+g \right\|_{L_w^p} \le \left\| f \right\|_{L_w^p} + \left\| g \right\|_{L_w^p}
\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\left\| X+Y \right\|_p \le \left\| X \right\|_p + \left\| Y \right\|_p.
\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
Note that $f_X(x)$ in equation \eqref{1} can be viewed as the "weight" of $|X|^p$. Therefore, (using weighted norm in $L_w^p$ space), the triangle inequality \eqref{3} can be written as:
$$
\left\| Z \right\|_{L_{h_Z(z)}^p} \le \left\| X \right\|_{L_{f_X(x)}^p} + \left\| Y \right\|_{L_{g_Y(y)}^p}
$$
where $Z=X+Y$ is another R.V., $f_X(x)$, $g_Y(y)$ and $h_Z(z)$ is the p.d.f. of R.V. $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.
However, this is NOT the triangle inequality in $L_w^p$ space since the norm operation was done in three different spaces: $L_{h_Z(z)}^p$, $L_{f_X(x)}^p$, $L_{g_Y(y)}^p$. But it really resembles equation \eqref{2}. How could I understand this?

Are you sure of your inequality? Feels like there should be some cross terms that come up.

@MarkSchultz-Wu I'm pretty sure that the inequality (2) and (3) holds when p>1. I learned the p-norm of random variables here.

I don't know what's so surprising about this, but maybe I misunderstood the question. Both inequalities are just instances of the general triangle inequality on $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ for some measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality.
In the first case the corresponding measure space is e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel or Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and measure $\mu(\mathrm{d}x) = w(x) \mathrm{d}x$.
In the second case the corresponding measure space is the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ on which $X, Y, Z$ are defined.
Of course it is not true that every random variable has a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure as you implicitly assumed and even if $X, Y$ possess a density, $Z = X+Y$ doesn't have to (think $Y = -X$ for example).
Even assuming this, it is not correct that \eqref{3} can be written as
$$
\left\| Z \right\|_{L_{h_Z(z)}^p} \le \left\| X \right\|_{L_{f_X(x)}^p} + \left\| Y \right\|_{L_{g_Y(y)}^p}.
$$
First, this does not even make sense, because in general $\Omega \neq \mathbb{R}$.
The correct version would be (assuming the densities exist)
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert x \vert^p f_Z(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}
= \Vert X + Y\Vert_{L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)}
\leq \Vert X \Vert_{L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)} + \Vert  Y\Vert_{L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)}  \\
= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert x \vert^p f_X(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p} + \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert x \vert^p f_Y(x)  \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p},
$$ which is evidently not in the form of (2).
If $X, Y$ have a joint density $f_{X, Y}$, then
$$
\Vert X + Y\Vert_{L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)}
= \mathbb{E}[\vert X + Y\vert^p]^{1/p}
= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}   \, \vert x+y\vert^p f_{X, Y}(x, y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)^{1/p}
\leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}   \, \vert x\vert^p f_{X, Y}(x, y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)^{1/p} + \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}   \, \vert y\vert^p f_{X}(x, y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)^{1/p}\\
= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}   \, \vert x\vert^p f_{X}(x) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)^{1/p} + \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}   \, \vert y\vert^p f_{Y}(y) \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\right)^{1/p}\\
= \Vert X \Vert_{L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)} + \Vert Y\Vert_{L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)},
$$ hence you can understand at least this case using the triangle inequality for a weighted $L^p$ space on $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ (and the general case could then be recovered by extending the probability space and adding an independent Gaussian $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \epsilon I_2)$ to $(X, Y)$).

In what you're calling the $L_w^p$-norm, I assume $w:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+$ is some measurable function, and the integral defining $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{L_w^p}$ is the Lebesgue integral.
If this is what you meant, then these are both special cases of an $L^p$ norm on a measure space. Given a measure space $(M,\Sigma,\mu)$, the space $L^p(M,\Sigma,\mu)$ is the space of $\Sigma$-measurable functions $f:M\to\mathbb R$, modulo $\mu$-almost everywhere equivalence, for which the Lebesgue integral $$\left\Vert \int |f|^p \text{ d}\mu\right\Vert$$ is finite.
Your $L_w^p$-norm is the special case where the underlying measurable space is the reals, and the measure is given by $\mu(A):=\int_A w(x) \text{ d}x$. The random variable one is just what I've written here for the special case that $\mu$ is a probability measure.
[I phrased things for $1\leq p <\infty$, but analogous statements hold for $p=\infty$ too.]
